# Numerical Integral of an oscillatory function

Tags: numerical-integration

I am struggling in trying to compute the following function:

[image]

I want to preform the calculation numerically, so I used the function [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) and I have shifted a bit the contour of integration in the imaginary plane to suppress the integral at the infinity but it doesn't work (the plot I obtain is totally different). That's what I did:

```
d[\[Nu]_] := 
 Re[Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] NIntegrate[(-x)^(1/2) HankelH1[\[Nu], -x] E^(-I x), {x, -\[Infinity] (1 + I 10^-5), 0}, MaxRecursion -> 100]]
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: First you should tell MMA that nue is numeric. Second I'm not sure wether you should put the Re[]-function inside the integral : d[nue_?NumericQ] := 
 Sqrt[\[Pi]/
    2] NIntegrate[(-x)^(1/2) Re[
     HankelH1[nue, -x] Exp[-I x]], {x, -\[Infinity]   , 0} ]

Comment: Is $H_\nu^{(1)}(-x)$ the `HankelH1` function or the `SphericalHankelH1` one? They are related but...